# How to load a firebase-collection with all its subcollection in one promise?

Tags: rxjs, angularfire2, angularfire, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am currently trying to figure out how to load an angular/fire-collection including all of its subcollections with RxJS.

This is my current approach:

```
return this.collectionRef.valueChanges().pipe(
      flatMap((entities: Entity[]) => entity),
      mergeMap((entity: Entity) => this.setSubCollection1(entity)),
      mergeMap((entity: Entity) => this.setSubCollection2(entity)),
      scan((entities: Entity[], entity: Entity) => entities.filter(a => a.id !== entity.id).concat(entity), [])
    );
```

and to load the documents in their subcollections

```
  private setSubCollection1 = (entity: Entity): Observable<Entity> => {
    return this.subCollectionRef.valueChanges(actor).pipe(
      map((subEntities1: SubEntity1[]) => {
        entity.subEntities1 = subEntities1;
        return entity;
      })
    );
  }
```

It works fine when having a full stream.
But now I wanted to get all of data in one single Promise: I already tried `.first().toPromise()` but this only gets the first entry, and does not finish if the collection has no entries. Using `reduce` in the query also does not work, because `valueChanges()` never finishes.

Am I using the wrong operators? Or any other ideas on how to solve that?

I hope to hear from you.